# 【Android】In-app purchases for non-public apps

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to continue to use Google Play billing when an application (with in-app billing already implemented) that has been published on Google Play is made private?
Should the billing function of Google Play also be made private?

Answer (score 0):

If you distribute the private app via Google Play you can still use the IAP feature.